# How to Convert SQL Server Query to MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, xml, if-statement, insert, insert-update

I'm trying to convert this SQL Server query to MySQL query
how can i do that?
Fallowing is my SQL server query. I need to convert this query to execute in MySQL.
EpfNO is the Primary key and IsValidUser = '1' is the condition that i need to check before insert. This query work perfectly in SQL Server but i need to do same thing in MySQL Database.

This is SQL Server query.

```
IF EXISTS 
(SELECT EpfNo FROM    dbo.[User] WHERE   EpfNo = {0})
BEGIN UPDATE  [User]
SET     UserName ={1},UserType ={2},IsValidUser = {3},Title = 
{4},DisplayName ={5},EmailAddress ={6},ContactNo ={7},
Extention = {8},Department ={9},Designation ={10},Location ={11}
FROM    [User]
WHERE   EpfNo ={0};
END;

ELSE
if({3} = '1')
BEGIN
INSERT  INTO dbo.[User] (EpfNo,UserName,UserType,IsValidUser,Title,DisplayName,EmailAddress,ContactNo,Extention,Department,Designation,Location) VALUES  ({0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6},{7},{8},{9},{10},{11}); END;
```

Comment: *i want to Modify check IsValidUser type is 0 or 1. If IsValidUser type is 1 then insert else update.* Illogical. INSERT .. ODKU selects the action depends on the duplicate violation occurence. If you want the action depend on the some external parameter value then use 2 separate queries, maybe in stored procedure format.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.